Resolve Relative Paths in local html file viewed in WebView2
I have a html files stored locally and want to show it in the WebView2 control, so I would use .Navigate("C:\temp\some.html") that all works fine.  In those HTML files I have css links using relative paths:
<link href="/service/css/rendering/rendering.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

When the html is shown, the css won't be loaded as the relative path can't be resolved.
Now I have seen (but don't have access to source code) where using the old Windows WebBrowser Control a html file with relative paths did load the css file.
Is there a way of setting a domain or similar to resolve the relative paths in the WebView2 control?  My current option is to update the file with the full web path, but if possible I would like to avoid this.  Viewing the pages live is not an option due to the process this is part of.
I didn't mention I also want scripts (if present) to run, as I thought they would be handled the same way, but testing this using <base> I have found that css loads, but scripts do not unless I give them a full path,

If you can modify the HTML content before loading it, adding a  tag can help resolve relative paths.
Add this line inside the  section of your HTML:

This tells the WebView2 control to resolve any relative paths (like /service/css/rendering/rendering.css) against C:\temp.

I see, so it would be adding the url to the href of where the html files came from originally, not a file path in my case.

Adding a <base href ... /> will indeed resolve the  css location (relative to the base) but it will set the base for all other relative paths in the html (to images and other resources. if any) which would normally resolve relative to the html file's location.
I would rather keep the paths to the resources and set the absolute path to the css.
